# Sorting HashMap using its list values in Android (Map<Integer, List<Item>>)

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have created a HashMap using json response which I want to use its data group by month.

My json

```
[
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"01. Less than 0",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":173
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"02. 1-5",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":445
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"03. 6-10",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":362
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"04. 11-15",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":241
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"05. 16-20",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":130
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"06. 21-25",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":115
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"07. 26-30",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":66
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"08. 31-35",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":32
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"09. More than 35",
      "month":11,
      "year":2020,
      "count":251
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"01. Less than 0",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":257
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"02. 1-5",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":726
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"03. 6-10",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":722
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"04. 11-15",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":378
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"05. 16-20",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":207
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"06. 21-25",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":151
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"07. 26-30",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":94
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"08. 31-35",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":56
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"09. More than 35",
      "month":12,
      "year":2020,
      "count":351
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"01. Less than 0",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":254
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"02. 1-5",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":693
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"03. 6-10",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":538
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"04. 11-15",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":287
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"05. 16-20",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":194
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"06. 21-25",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":144
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"07. 26-30",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":110
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"08. 31-35",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":73
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"09. More than 35",
      "month":1,
      "year":2021,
      "count":372
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"01. Less than 0",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":225
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"02. 1-5",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":960
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"03. 6-10",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":733
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"04. 11-15",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":360
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"05. 16-20",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":200
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"06. 21-25",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":145
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"07. 26-30",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":107
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"08. 31-35",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":51
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"09. More than 35",
      "month":2,
      "year":2021,
      "count":271
   }
]
```

Object class

```
public class Item{

    private String type;
    private String category;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private String monthName;
    private String count;

}


                JSONArray resArray = new JSONArray(jsonresponse);
                for (int i = 0; i < resArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jo = resArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item ariData = new Item();
                    ariData.setType(jo.getString("type"));
                    ariData.setCategory(jo.getString("category"));
                    ariData.setYear(jo.getInt("year"));
                    ariData.setMonth(jo.getInt("month"));
                    ariData.setMonthName(getMonthFullName(jo.getInt("month")));
                    ariData.setCount(jo.getString("count"));
                    ariList.add(ariData);

                }
```

I want to display same month's data in a RecyclerView so I have grouped by this json its Month for display in the RecyclerView. So I put it into a HashMap using..

```
Map<Integer, List<Item>> objectsPer = ariList.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getMonth));
```

Problem is, If there is two years' data for example **2020-12** and **2021-01** then **2020-12** month's data display after **2021-01** data. I know this is happening because of the group by using month. I want to sort this HashMap using year also.

**Edit**

```
public class Item{

private String type;
private String category;
private String count;
private int total;
private YearMonth yearMonth;

}

  JSONArray resArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < resArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jo = resArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Item ariData = new Item();
                            ariData.setType(jo.getString("type"));
                            ariData.setCategory(jo.getString("category"));
                            ariData.setCount(jo.getString("count"));
                            YearMonth yMonth = YearMonth.of(jo.getInt("year"), jo.getInt("month"));
                            ariData.setYearMonth(yMonth);
                            ariList.add(ariData);

                        }

                        Map<YearMonth, List<Item>> objectsPer = ariList.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getYearMonth));
```

Here I put date range in **2021-03 to 2021-06**

see the debug I get for this date range after group by using year month

[image]

Here I put date range in **2020-11 to 2021-06**

[image]

Comment: If you group by month only, 1 will always be before 12... You have to consider the year, too. Hint: You can use a `java.time.YearMonth`.

Comment: can I do multiple grouping like **Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getYear, Item::getMonth)** ? I tried by this is not working

Comment: That's why I involved the `YearMonth`, make an `Item` have a `YearMonth` instead of a year, a month and a month name. This class provides each of those and you can group by that attribute and the sorting will be as desired. You can instantiate it by `YearMonth.of(int year, int month)` and get the month name by `yearMonth.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);`.

Comment: It worked like 202012 comes first but 2021 values come like 202103,202102,202101.

For ex : date range 2021-11 to 2021-03
then **202011,202012,202103,202102,202101**,
But i want **202011,202012,202101,202102,202103**

Comment: How did you use it? Can you [edit] your question and include the code that produces this weird result?

Comment: You have posted images of the output (?), but I was asking for the code that produces this output.

Comment: I have added the string response converted in to list part also. This output generated by **Map<YearMonth, List<Item>> objectsPer = ariList.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getYearMonth));**

Comment: Then try this line: `NavigableMap<YearMonth, Set<Item>> objectsPer = ariList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getYearMonth, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toSet()));`

Comment: @deHaar thankx. I tried 
**Map<YearMonth, List<Item>> unsortMap = ariList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getYearMonth));
Map<YearMonth, List<Item>> sortMap = new TreeMap<>(unsortMap);** 

It also worked, your solution also worked

Answer (score 1):

## `YearMonth`

As commented by deHaar, you should be using the `java.time.YearMonth` class rather than your separate `int` fields for year and for month. And no need for storing month name as that can be determined dynamically by calling `YearMonth#getMonth` and `Month#getDisplayName`.

Redefine your class, with less fields: String type, String category, YearMonth yearMonth,  int count.

(Shouldn’t `count` be an integer number rather than `String`?)

By the way, in Java 16+, we can define a class more briefly as a record if its main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. Simply declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. You can even declare a record locally.

```
public record Item ( String type, String category, YearMonth yearMonth,  int count ) {}
```

You could just as well define a conventional class in the context of this Answer. A record is simply more convenient.

By the way, `type` and `category` should probably be defined each in their own enum rather than as `String`. But that’s a whole other matter.

## `NavigableMap`, `NavigableSet`

Collect your `Item` objects in a map. Use a navigable map and navigable set to keep sorted by `YearMonth`.

Perhaps use `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` as your choice of implementations. When constructing the `TreeSet` objects, pass a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to organize the sorting.

```
NavigableMap< YearMonth , NavigableSet< Item > > = …
```

Comment: count is int value. I am not familiar with NavigableMap. I tried and I am getting error when I use 
**NavigableMap<YearMonth, NavigableSet<Item >> objectsPer = ariList.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item ::getYearMonth));**

Comment: @D.madushanka Past my bedtime, but I may be able to write more code on another day. All this has been covered  already on Stack Overflow if you search to learn more.